# jQuery, ajax multiple checkboxes into $_POST array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, checkbox

I'm trying to send $_POST data to another page to add sessions for a simple shopping cart.

I have a multiple forms within a PHP while loop each with multiple checkboxes, everything works apart from the checkboxes.

My question is how do I change this piece of code to change "item_extras" into an array?

> if(this.checked) item_extras = $(this).val();

I have tried the following but, this just creates one line with all the values instead of another row within the array. If this is too confusing I could create a sample if it helps.

> if(this.checked) item_extras += $(this).val();

```
$('form[id^="add_item_form"]').on('submit', function(){
    //alert("On Click Works");
    event.preventDefault();
    addItem($(this));
});

function addItem(ele) {
    //alert("I'm in the addItem Function");
    var item_id = ele.parent().parent().find("input[name=item_id]").val(); // get item id
    var item_name = ele.parent().parent().find("input[name=item_name]").val(); // get item name
    var item_options = ele.parent().parent().find('#options').val(); // get selected option
    var item_extras = "";

    $item_extras = ele.parent().parent().find('input[name^="extra"]'); // find all extras

    $item_extras.each(function() {
        if(this.checked) item_extras = $(this).val(); // how do i make this into an array???
    });

    alert("BEFORE AJAX");

    var dataString = 'item_id=' + item_id + '&item_name=' + item_name + '&item_options=' + item_options + '&item_extras[]=' + item_extras;

    alert(dataString);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "includes/cart.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'includes/cart.php',
                success: function(data) {
                $('#cart').html(data);
                alert("AJAX SUCCESS");
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Try `item_extras += '&item_extras[]=' + $(this).val();`

Comment: Are you using an array name in your form?

Comment: Thanks Victor that worked a treat :)

Answer (score 3):

you can use serialize method.  [Form.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
   var data = $(this).serialize();
});
```